# Getting Problem to add Pay SDK in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, payment-gateway, payment, razorpay

I need to integrate into a PayU application for Android, I downloaded the files and integrate them into a new module. When you finish compiling, throw this error.
here is build.grdle:app file

```
   plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.revivale.trades"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "52e39243-b5a1-457d-bed2-a92c33a6cca2", onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/"
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'

    implementation 'com.braintreepayments:card-form:4.+'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:4.+'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.+'



    implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0'
    implementation 'ai.devsupport.instamojo:instamojolib:0.1.6'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.1'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:26.0-android'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.1'

    //State Progress Bar
    implementation 'com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar:stateprogressbar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'hyogeun.github.com.colorratingbar:ColorRatingBar:1.0.1'


    // Pay UMoney
    //implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.5.0' // OLD
    implementation 'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.6.0' // NEW

    // RazorPay SDK
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.4'

    //No Internet available
    implementation 'am.appwise.components:NoInternetDialog:1.1.3'

    /*Expandable Recyclerview*/
    implementation 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:1.0.0'

    // paytm

    implementation('com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.4.4') {
        transitive = true;
    }


    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


build.grdle:project file

buildscript {
    repositories {

        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io"}
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url "https://phonepe.bintray.com/PhonePeIntentSDK"
        }

        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**

when I build a project, error shows Could not GET 'https://phonepe.bintray.com/PhonePeIntentSDK/com/braintreepayments/card-form/maven-metadata.xml'
please help me to build the project successfully.

**

Comment: getting problem in phonepe.bintray.com and unable to resolve for many dayz

Comment: Same issue, any solution?